Resource Request: Copies of the various biographies of Shri Adi Sankaracharya
I am interested in learning about the various biographies of Shri Adi Shankaracharya. My interest sprouted when I was reading about the traditional and historical views of the Acharya in this link. Important quotes that struck me were the following:


Scholars have questioned Shankara's early influence in India.[11] The Buddhist scholar Richard E. King states, "Although it is common to find Western scholars and Hindus arguing that Sankaracarya was the most influential and important figure in the history of Hindu intellectual thought, this does not seem to be justified by the historical evidence.[7]" According to Clark, "Sankara was relatively unknown during his life-time, and probably for several centuries after, as there is no mention of him in Buddhist or jain sources for centuries; nor is he mentioned by other important philosophers of the ninth and tenth centuries."[10] According to King and Roodurmun, until the 10th century Shankara was overshadowed by his older contemporary Mandana-Misra, the latter considered to be the major representative of Advaita




Hajime Nakamura states that prior to Shankara, views similar to his already existed, but did not occupy a dominant position within the Vedanta.[69] Until the 11th century, Vedanta itself was a peripheral school of thought;[70] Vedanta became a major influence when it was utilized by various sects of Hinduism to ground their doctrines.[71] The early Vedanta scholars were from the upper classes of society, well-educated in traditional culture. They formed a social elite, "sharply distinguished from the general practitioners and theologians of Hinduism."[72] Their teachings were "transmitted among a small number of selected intellectuals".[72]




Vidyaranya was an influential Advaitin, and he created legends to turn Shankara, whose elevated philosophy had no appeal to gain widespread popularity, into a "divine folk-hero who spread his teaching through his digvijaya ("universal conquest," see below) all over India like a victorious conqueror."[81][82] In his doxography Sarvadarśanasaṅgraha ("Summary of all views") Vidyaranya presented Shankara's teachings as the summit of all darsanas, presenting the other darsanas as partial truths which converged in Shankara's teachings, which was regarded to be the most inclusive system.[83][81] The Vaishanava traditions of Dvaita and Visishtadvaita were not classified as Vedanta, and placed just above Buddhism and Jainism, reflecting the threat they posed for Vidyaranya's Advaita allegiance.[84] Bhedabheda wasn't mentioned at all, "literally written out of the history of Indian philosophy."[85]


These suggested to me that Shri Adi Sankaracharya was not well known during his lifetime and several centuries later. It could be possible that the popularity of Advaita grew slowly until the 1000s due to rejections from the "general practitioners and theologians," many of whom were the "Vaishnava traditions." He might have become a fad in several localities ("the sharply distinguished" "social elites") in different sections of Bharata during his lifetime, a fad that grew into a powerful and popular school of Vedanta several centuries later. The development of Advaita, though based on the works of Shri Sankaracharya, Shri Govindapada, and Shri Goudapada, might rest on the shoulders and literary works of people after them.
While reading the Manimanjari from this source, I came across the following notes made by the translator:

I did some online searching and found that Anandagiri lived in the 1200s (about 500 years after the Acharya), Vidyaranya lived from 1296 to 1391 (a century after Anandagiri and therefore 600 years after the Acharya), and Purushottama Bharati lived from 1408 to 1448 (a century after Vidyaranya and so 700 years after the Acharya). The ones I cited are, interestingly, from dates after the 11th century.
I like to know whether these works diverge only in the birth story of the famous Acharya. I only have the copy of Vidyaranya's work. Can anyone please provide copies of the works of the other authors, or Vedantic works that cite and mention passages from these authors' works?
